# Why child process is required when threads can be used instead

Tags: operating-system

What is the real distinction between threads and child process with respect to their use case or purpose? AFAIK they both do takes up the duty of process and executes it. What are the scenarios where only child process can be used and similarly for threads?

Comment: Found this, http://www.geekride.com/fork-forking-vs-threading-thread-linux-kernel/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The scenarios can be several, like

1)As the threads share the same memory space with the parent, the application in which contention between the sub-processes should not be present, in those applications, threads cannot be used.

2)If in your application, the spawning of sub-processes are controlled by some event (like requests in a server program), then it is better to use threads. Because if there are a large number of child processes created, then memory resources might fall short.